# How do you uninstall Flutter completely and properly from a Mac?

Tags: flutter

I need to uninstall Flutter completely from my Mac. However, I cannot find any documentation that can help me with that.

Comment: @Train it looks they is no articles, properly specifies what are the thinks to remove to completely uninstall flutter.

Comment: @Pedram-1 Please check which answer helped you understand and mark it as correct. It will help future users with the same issue.

Answer (score 42):

Flutter is an SDK that you download and unpack onto a directory in your Mac. There is no automatic uninstall process in the same way that there is no automatic install process. You "installed" it by downloading a zip file and unzipping it. All you have to do is remove the contents of the directory where you unzipped it in.

Even the path addition to be able to call the *flutter* command from anywhere in your system has to be done manually. If you did that, then you can remove it as well from your shell's PATH.

Answer (score 26):

just `rm -rf` the sdk folder, or if you just want to clean a corrupt
run the following commands in the Flutter install directory:

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

Comment: I still had flutter paths from this directory being exported into my PATH environment variable on my mac. I edited `~/.zshrc` manually to get rid of those.

Answer (score 21):

To find your flutter sdk installed path. use `which flutter` command and then delete the Flutter SDK folder.

Note: This command only works if you set the path correctly.

Answer (score 3):

To uninstall flutter from Mac OS M1, here are the steps you can take:

1. Check flutter path `which flutter`
2. cd to that directory
3. remove the directory `rm -rf flutter`
4. check the command again `which flutter`, you will get this message `flutter not found`

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

`snap remove flutter`

Comment: This will only work for users who installed Flutter with the snap package manager

Answer (score 2):

For those who installed flutter with brew, it’s best practice to also uninstall with brew.

```
brew uninstall flutter
```

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall flutter from a Mac using the command line :

1.Open Terminal.

2.In Terminal, type the following command to list all the installed applications:
`ls /Applications`

```
cd ~/flutter
```

3.To uninstall the flutter application, use the command:

```
sudo ./flutter/uninstall


sudo rm -rf /Applications/Flutter.app
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have HomeBrew installed on your Mac OS, just execute below command in your terminal

```
brew remove flutter
```

This command will uninstall Flutter completely and properly from your Mac

Answer (score -4):

This worked for me actually:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g flutter-cli
```

Comment: This command only deletes the Flutter CLI, not the Flutter SDK.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli