# How to uninstall flutter in mac?

Tags: flutter, dart, uninstallation, macos-catalina

I want to uninstall flutter in mac and make sure no related configuration files are there in the mac catalina

how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you uninstall Flutter completely and properly from a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760735/how-do-you-uninstall-flutter-completely-and-properly-from-a-mac)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You extracted a zip to install Flutter. You probably also set the path.

This should use the path to find the Flutter installation and remove it:

```
rm -rf `dirname \`which flutter\``/..
```

Then you should edit the `.zshenv` file in your home directory and remove the line that adds Flutter to path:

```
open -a TextEdit ~/.zshenv
```

Then edit it so:

```
...
# FIND THIS LINE BELOW THAT HAS Flutter AND REMOVE THAT LINE
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/$USER/Flutter/flutter/bin 
...
```

Also, there are some config files in your home directory:

```
ls -al

drwxr-xr-x    3 user  staff         96 Jul 12 19:51 .dart
drwxr-xr-x    4 user  staff        128 Jul 12 19:51 .dartServer
-rw-r--r--    1 user  staff         78 Jul 12 19:51 .flutter
-rw-r--r--    1 user  staff         25 Jul 14 10:30 .flutter_settings
-rw-r--r--    1 user  staff        210 Oct 17 09:47 .flutter_tool_state
```

You can remove these as such:

```
rm -rf ~/.dart*
rm -rf ~/.flutter*
```

This should take care of removing Flutter from your system. You can also open your IDE and remove the Flutter and Dart plugins to complete the picture. Sorry to see you go!

Comment: I am not leaving the flutter, it's just that I am cleaning my system as I am facing the issues with flutter libraries after upgrading it