# How to delete then reinstall Flutter

Tags: flutter

Whenever I have a problem with Flutter I often find answers saying 'reinstall the Flutter SDK'.

However I cannot find any clear instructions on how to do this (please direct me to them if I am wrong).

**General Questions**

By 'clear' instructions, I mean ones that answer the following questions:

1. What folder(s) should be deleted to remove Flutter from my computer?
2. Do any files need to be copied and added to the new Flutter folder once I reinstall it?
3. Do I need to make any changes to my Flutter projects either before or after reinstalling Flutter?
4. Will I need to download the same channel (stable, beta, dev, master) as what I am currently on?
5. Will I need to make any changes to my PATH?

**Are these the correct steps to reinstall?**

1. Go to https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos
2. Download the zip of the release you want (safest to use latest stable version)
3. Open Flutter zip in SAME location as the previous Flutter folder was
4. Done - I should now be able to run Flutter projects without any further steps

Apologies if these seem like very basic questions but for someone fairly new it isn't obvious what the answers are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you uninstall Flutter completely and properly from a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760735/how-do-you-uninstall-flutter-completely-and-properly-from-a-mac)

Comment: Flagged this to close as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760735/how-do-you-uninstall-flutter-completely-and-properly-from-a-mac). As far as I am aware, Flutter only requires you to unzip a package and add it to the $PATH. Thus you only need, like explained in the linked answer, to remove the "Flutter" directory. As far as installing, Flutter has a seemingly good [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos).

Comment: Yes I have seen that before - it certainly helps with uninstalling. But it does not answer the re-install part, which is the key part of my question. For example are there any cache files or git files that I will need to keep to ensure my apps still work? I don't think that is covered in the question you linked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm new to Flutter and had similar issues. I will outline what worked for me but meanwhile, to answer your questions:

> What folder(s) should be deleted to remove Flutter from my computer?

The Flutter folder which you unzipped and, presumably added to $PATH. Although not deleting it isn't going to pose an issue. I have separate folders of different versions of Flutter on my computer and it's fine.

> Do any files need to be copied and added to the new Flutter folder
> once I reinstall it?

Try a fresh download of Flutter and unzip it? There is no need to copy or add any files to the Flutter folder once you've (re)installed it.

> Do I need to make any changes to my Flutter projects either before or
> after reinstalling Flutter?

Not exactly sure what you mean by make changes to your Flutter projects. If you ran `flutter doctor` and didn't get any errors, then it's good to go. When you create a new Flutter project either in Android Studio, VS Code or Terminal, it will automatically handle whatever file copying business.

> Will I need to download the same channel (stable, beta, dev, master)
> as what I am currently on?

No, you only need one. I suggest you download one from Stable unless you need web support, which would be Beta.

> Will I need to make any changes to my PATH?

After you've unzipped your fresh copy of Flutter (note the folder destination), open Terminal and change the path to said folder destination but make sure it's the /bin folder you're mapping to.

> Are these the correct steps to reinstall?
>
> Go to
> https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos
> Download the zip of the release you want (safest to use latest stable
> version) Open Flutter zip in SAME location as the previous Flutter
> folder was Done - I should now be able to run Flutter projects without
> any further steps

Yes and no. You're missing a number of steps. Please follow the [full Flutter installation guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install) depending on your OS.

It took me about 10 hours over two days and a VPN to finally get it working in China with an old install from two years ago when I was in Montréal.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know of is to execute the following command from a terminal window or command prompt:

`flutter downgrade && flutter upgrade`

Comment: Error: There is no previously recorded version for channel "stable"