# need to solved this problem flutter in mac

Tags: flutter

Building flutter tool...
Failed to start the Dart CLI isolate. Could not resolve DartDev snapshot or kernel.
(null).
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
Failed to start the Dart CLI isolate. Could not resolve DartDev snapshot or kernel.
(null).
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (8 tries left)
Failed to start the Dart CLI isolate. Could not resolve DartDev snapshot or kernel.

i need to solved in mac

```
Building flutter tool...
Failed to start the Dart CLI isolate. Could not resolve DartDev snapshot or kernel.
(null).
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
Failed to start the Dart CLI isolate. Could not resolve DartDev snapshot or kernel.
(null).
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (8 tries left)
Failed to start the Dart CLI isolate. Could not resolve DartDev snapshot or kernel.
```

Answer (score 0):

First run Flutter Doctor in your terminal to check for any issues with your Flutter installation.

```
flutter doctor
```

If OK

```
flutter upgrade
flutter clean
flutter pub upgrade
rm pubspec.lock
flutter pub get
```

If none of the above steps work, you may consider reinstalling Flutter.

Comment: how to  reinstalling Flutter

Comment: Remove the existing Flutter directory and clone it again from the official repository

Comment: can you explain please steps this the first time

Comment: [how-do-you-uninstall-flutter-completely-and-properly-from-a-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760735/) here you can find how to uninstall